# Why getcontentpane() is undefined?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

I have a code here and I get this error. How do I fix the error for the code below?

```
Container container = getContentPane();
```

Here is the running code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ModelJTable{
  private DefaultTableModel model;

  private JTable table;

  public ModelJTable() {
    super();
    model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.addColumn("Product Name");
    model.addColumn("Price");
    model.addColumn("Quantity");
    model.addColumn("Subtotal");

    String[] socrates = { "Socrates", "", "469-399 B.C." };
    model.addRow(socrates);
    table = new JTable(model);

    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add Philosopher");
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String[] philosopher = { "", "", "" };
        model.addRow(philosopher);
      }
    });

    JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove Selected Philosopher");

    removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
      }
    });
    JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel.add(addButton);
    inputPanel.add(removeButton);

    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    container.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    Global.uniFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Global.uniFrame.setSize(800, 300);
    Global.uniFrame.setVisible(true);
  } 
  public static class Global{
      public static JFrame uniFrame = new JFrame();
  }
  private static void createGUI(){
      new ModelJTable();
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      createGUI();
  }
}
```

I change the code to this and it doesn't display the contents.

```
Container container = new Container();
container.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
container.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
Global.uniFrame.getContentPane();
Global.uniFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Global.uniFrame.setSize(800, 300);
Global.uniFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Replace `Container container = new Container();` with `Container container = Global.uniFrame.getContentPane();`

Answer (score 4):

Because your class doesn't extend from anything that provides that method

```
public class ModelJTable{
```

nor does you current class implement such a method...

The only possible class (within your example) that could provide this functionality is the `uniFrame` in the `Global` class

```
... = Global.uniFrame.getContentPane();
```

To be honest, I would seriously avoid `static` references to ANY gui component, especially when they are not defined `final`.  There is to much risk that the `static` reference will be changed or, if declared `final` locks you into a single possibility.

There is a also the risk that some other piece of code might try and do something it shouldn't, like remove everything...

Answer (score 2):

There is no method `getContentPane()`. You probably forgot to extend another class.

Comment: is there another way for me to declare it without extending JFrame on my class?

Comment: Yes, like a normal method. You can get the content pane with: `Global.uniFrame.getContentPane()`.